# Why can't operator () of stateless functor be static?

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, c++14, functor

Why is `operator ()` of stateless functor not allowed to be `static`? Stateless lambda objects are convertible to pointers to free functions having the same signature as their `operator ()`.

[Stephan T. Lavavej](http://1drv.ms/1j4yRtz) on p. 6 points out that conversion to a function pointer *is just an `operator FunctionPointer()`* (cite). But I can't obtain a corresponding pointer to `operator ()` as to non-member function. For functor `struct F { void operator () () {} }` it seems to be impossible to convert `&F::operator ()` to instance of type `using P = void (*)();`.

Code:

```
struct L
{
    static
    void operator () () const {} 
    operator auto () const
    { 
        return &L::operator ();
    }
};
```

The error is

> overloaded 'operator()' cannot be a static member function

but `operator ()` is not overloaded.

Comment: If your functor class is stateless, what's the point of having a class rather than simply a function`?

Comment: All `operator` functions of a class are considered "overloaded operators"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It does not matter in sense of this (non-practical) question. If my code is library one, then I should be able to maintain all the possible types provided by user.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to "emulate" a behaviour of stateless lambda-function.

Comment: It won't be possible. If you do e.g. `L()` you construct an instance of the `L` class, not call its static `operator()` function. It's hardwired into the grammar of C++.

Comment: The point of class operators is that they operate on an object of that lass. So it makes no sense for the compiler to allow class operators to be static. But you can still use a static function as your functor, it just can't be a class operator.

Comment: If it helps imagine what a static version of `operator++()` would mean?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The language could simply not allow overloads which would be ambiguous with constructors. So, for example, if you delete the default constructor for `L`, then `L()` wouldn't construct an instance of `L`, and you would be allowed to overload static `operator()()`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The language *could* be like that, but it's not defined to be that way now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Of course. The question is about what the language could be like. Your comment though reads (to me) like the grammar is just stuck the way it is, and that this would be some kind of breaking change, or that it's just not compatible with the way the language is now.

Comment: To give a real-life example, stateless functors in C++ are useful to circumvent another language limitation: partial template specialisation. You can do that to functor classes, but you cannot do it on plain functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ty for providing the only correct answer to this question, i was at loss why it wasnt allowed until the ambiguity with constructors was pointed out which seems a sound enough reason

Comment: C++23 made `static operator()` real (as well as `static operator[]`)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: it could be possible to use `L::operator()`

Comment: @MooingDuck True, but then that would kind of negate the usefulness of operator overloading. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per standard [[over.oper] p6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/over.oper#6):

> **An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function** and have
> at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
> enumeration.

Additionally, in [[over.call] p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/over.call#1) it is stated that:

> `operator()` shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters. It can have
> default arguments. It implements the function call syntax
>
> *postfix-expression* `(` *expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)`
>
> where the *postfix-expression*
> evaluates to a class object and the possibly empty *expression-list*
> matches
> the parameter list of an `operator()`
> member function of the class. Thus, a call
> `x(arg1,...)`
> is interpreted
> as
> `x.operator()(arg1, ...)`
> for a class object
> `x` of type `T`.

---

*Note: These restrictions have been lifted in C++23, so `operator()` can be `static`.*

Comment: But what the logical reason for this? Either way I should accept the answer due to my poor question formulation =).

Comment: @Orien Users here may be able to guess their reasoning, but for a definitive answer on that question, I think you would have to direct it at The Committee.

Comment: @Orient, I would say the logical reason is that all operators should behave in the same way. Also invoking an operator for a _class_ instead of an object just doesn't seem right. Unfortunately I don't know what exact reasons was the committee directed by when they were making the standard.

Comment: A good place to look for rationales is "The design and evolution..." book by Stroustrup. But chances are that there is no other rationale than keeping things simple.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I had some other ideas, too... :-(

Comment: Apart from scope resolution (which is special and also cannot be overloaded) - all operators operate on objects, not classes. Furthermore function operator is intended for function _objects_ and hence it would just add unnnecesary complexity if they could be static (you can just name your static function instead)

Answer (score 9):

Like the others, I don't see a fundamental reason why it is not possible to have a static `operator()`, for stateless functors or *in general*.

(EDIT 2020: Just found this proposal http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1169r0.html)

(UPDATE 2021: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1169r1.html)

In some cases might conflict, according to other rules, with member/static overloading which is not allowed in C++ (again, not sure why).

```
struct A{
  void f();
  static int f(); // compile error 
}
```

So even if it were allowed to have a `static operator()`, should this be permitted?

```
struct A{
  void operator()();
  static int operator()(); // should be a compiler error??? 
}
```

Anyway, there is only one true reason to have a `static operator()` that it is not purely a syntactic reason and it is that objects should be able to call static functions as if they were member functions.

```
struct A{
   static int f():
}
...
A a; 
a.f(); // calls A::f() !!!
```

Specifically, the user of the class `A` doesn't need to know if a function is implemented as static or as a member.
It can later be upgraded to a member function from a generic point of view.

Leaving that important application to generic programming aside, there is a workaround the leads to a similar *syntax* that I saw in https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/19/customization-points-for-functions/, and that is to have a static member function called `_`, a name that doesn't imply any meaning.

```
struct A{
    static int _();
}
...
A::_(); // instead of the more desirable (?) A::() or A::operator()
a._(); // this invokes the static functon _
```

Instead of the more desirable `A::()` or `A::operator()`, (well are they desirable at all? I don't know; something like `A()` would be really interesting but doens't even follow the syntax of a static function and can be confused with a constructor).

(As I said, the only feature I still miss, regarding this limitation you point out, is that `a()` cannot automatically delegate to a static version of the `operator()`, e.g. `A::operator()`.)

In summary, your code could look like this:

```
struct L{
    static void _() {} 
    auto operator()() const{ 
        return L::_();
    }
};

L ell; 
ell(); // calls L::_() really.
```

Not sure what are willing to achieve still.

---

One can "CRTP" the idea https://godbolt.org/z/74vxsTYxd

```
#include<utility> // forward

template<class Self>
struct stateless_functor_facade{
    template<class... Args>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const{
        return Self::operator_paren(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct square : stateless_functor_facade<square>{
    static auto operator_paren(double x){return x*x;}
};

int main(){
    square s;
    s(5);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I can't see any technical reason to forbid a `static auto operator()( ... )`. But it's a special case, so it would complicate the standard to add support for it. And such complication is not necessary, because it's very easy to emulate:

```
struct L
{
    static void func() {}

    void operator()() const { func(); }

    operator auto () const
    { 
        return &L::func;
    }
};
```

See [Johannes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776718/464581) for some possibly useful extra info.

Answer (score 7):

I would think that there's no technical reason to forbid this (but not being familiar with the de-facto cross-vendor C++ ABI (Itanium ABI), I can't promise anything).

There's however an evolutional issue about this at https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#88 . It even has the *[tiny]* mark on it, making it a somewhat "trivial" feature under consideration.

Comment: I think the real meaning of the *"tiny"* here means, that the *committee* understood they made a *mistake*, and they try to show it as it would be only a *tiny* one. Don't have illusions: if the only possible reason is that no one in the committee is a competent c++ programmer.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with C++23 both `operator()` ([P1169](https://wg21.link/P1169)) and `operator[]` ([P2589](https://wg21.link/P2589)) can be `static`. There was never really a good reason for the restriction, so it's finally being lifted.

You can also define a Lambda as `static` by `[] static { ... }`. If you have a Lambda without captures, you always should define it as `static`.

Unfortunately, this behavior cannot become the implicit standard without breaking API and ABI compatibility, so the explicit definition is necessary. Backwards compatibility is, as so often, both a blessing and a curse.

Answer (score 1):

i i'm not going to pretend to be an expert at all. however, i was looking into static lamdas or static operator() and theirs an ongoing proposal about it. i was satisfied with what i could understand.

it appears the ideas proposed is grappling with how to design it to not break other code.etc. however it appears their working on a solution. so. mabyeeee one day!

```
static operator() 
Document #: P1169R2  
Date:   2021-08-14
Project: Programming Language C++
```

> **3 Proposal**
>
> The proposal is to just allow the ability to make the call operator a
> static member function, instead of requiring it to be a non-static
> member function. We have many years of experience with member-less
> function objects being useful. Let’s remove the unnecessary object
> parameter overhead. There does not seem to be any value provided by
> this restriction.
>
> There are other operators that are currently required to be
> implemented as non-static member functions - all the unary operators,
> assignment, subscripting, conversion functions, and class member
> access. We do not believe that being able to declare any of these as
> static will have as much value, so we are not pursuing those at this
> time. We’re not aware of any use-case for making any of these other
> operators static, while the use-case of having stateless function
> objects is extremely common.

#### find full Document here:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1169r2.html

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to have static operator (), after `c++23` - go to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test#Language_features and look for `__cpp_static_call_operator`. GCC 13 will supports it - https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html.

[Here is an example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:16),source:%27struct+A+%7B%0A++++constexpr+static+int+operator()+(int+x)+noexcept+%7B%0A++++++++return+x+-+1%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++constexpr+static+int+operator%5B%5D+(int+x)+noexcept+%7B%0A++++++++return+x+-+1%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+f+%3D+%5B%5D(int+x)+constexpr+static+noexcept+%7B%0A++++++++return+x+-+1%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A++++return+f(A()(A()%5B3%5D))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.72845953002611,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B23+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.271540469973885,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with gcc trunk.

```
struct A {
    constexpr static int operator() (int x) noexcept { return x - 1; }
    constexpr static int operator[] (int x) noexcept { return x - 1; }
};

int main() {
    return [](int x) constexpr static noexcept { return x - 1; }( A()( A()[3] ));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple, a little bit dirty workaround until the relevant *committee* considers this trivial feature:

*Glob operators are syntactically similar to the constructors.*

Thus, you can't write a

```
static MyClass::operator()(...);
```

It was made simply impossible, because a *committee* decided so on unclear reasons. I would be so happy if I could talk with one of their members, to ask, what was in their mind as they decided so. Unfortunately, he probably wouldn't understand my question, because he never programmed c++. He only worked on its docs.

Now they need some decades of

- debates
- consultations
- meetings
- and considerations

to implement a trivial feature. I suspect the feature may be made available around in c++3x, and on emulated machines it may be even tried out.

Until then, you can try to write:

```
MyClass::MyClass(...);
```

In both cases you can call `MyClass(...);`.

Of course it is useful mainly if `MyClass` is a singleton. And, I would say it is a hack. Furthermore, it allocates a `sizeof(MyClass)` on the stack which may be bad in the performance / efficiency side.

---

Furthermore, this will be in essence a constructor, and constructors can't return anything. But you can avoid this by storing the result in the instance, and then casting it by a cast operator to anything you wish to.

Comment: ...and it cannot return anything. You then have to store the result and add a cast operator. (Good try anyway.)

Comment: @alfC Exactly! Thank you.