# Should I use a class with static members to implement Template Method Pattern if I don't need to take care of internal function state?

Tags: c++, json, qt, templates, design-patterns

The question is a bit confusing so let me clarify by explaining my predicament.

I'm using `nlohman::json` and trying to do conversions between `nlohman::json` value types and `QString`s from QT 5.8.   In order to do those conversions I came to the conclusion that I would need to use the json libraries `json::is_typexxx` for json value types. This ended up looking like this:

```
QString convertQString(const json &json_in) {
    if (json_in.is_number_integer()) {
        return //QString integer conversion
    } else if (json_in.is_number_float()) {
        return //QString float conversion
    } else if (json_in.is_string()) {
        return //QString std::string conversion
    } else if (json_in.is_boolean()) {
        return //QString bool conversion
    }
    return // QString no type found default
}
```

I soon realized that I would need to convert QStrings back into values for `nlohman::json`, in doing so I started to write the following function

```
void convertJson(.../**notimportant**/... json& json_out){
    ... /**more stuff here**/
    if (json_out.is_number_integer()) {
        ...
    } else if (json_out.is_number_float()) {
        ...
    } else if (json_out.is_string()) {
        ...
    } else if (json_out.is_boolean()) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and soon realized I was just writing the same logic for checking types.  Naturally I thought this was an excellent oportunity to use the Template Method Pattern, and started writing the following classes:

```
template<typename T>
class JsonChoice {
protected:
    T makechoice(const nlohmann::json &json_in);

    virtual T ifinteger() = 0;
    ...// other functions that follow the "iftypexxx()" convention
};

template<typename T>
T JsonChoice::choice(const nlohmann::json &json_in) {
    if (json_in.is_number_integer()) {
        return ifinteger();
    ... //you get the pattern... 
}

QStringConverter : public JsonChoice<QString>{
   ...
protected:
   QString ifinteger();
   ... //etc
};
// friend define operator ()?

JsonConverter : public JsonChoice<nlohmann::json>{
   ...
protected:
   nlohmann::json ifinteger();
   ... //etc
};
// friend define operator ()?
```

It was at this point that I realized I didn't need state in either of my Template Method Pattern functors.  However most examples I've seen of this pattern implemented are made like so:

```
TMPFunctor = tmpfun(statevar);
...
```

So I was wary of not following convention here, but since I didn't need any state, it didn't seem like it was a good idea to force myself to have to create a variable every time I wanted to use what was essentially a function with internal logic switched out depending on the signature.   I started wondering if I even should use functors to accomplish this task, as I could techinically template every part of the process to simply create one function as well.  Is this an adequate solution to this problem, to create a functor class with all static members, use it as a functor?

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776545/2036035) statically overloading () is a problem however and I'm not sure if I should just wrap another class function in another function like so to solve this issue:

```
QString convertQstring(const nlohmann::json &json_in){
    return QStringConverter.makechoice(json_in);
}
```

or just template every part of the function (which sounds annoying and ugly to me) to generalize the choice switch ie:

```
template<typename returnval, typename integerfunctemplate, ...>
returnval convert( const nlohmann::json &json_in){
    if (json_in.is_number_integer()) {
        return integerfunctemplate();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you can't use QVariant?

Comment: @BruceFeldman I'm not sure how QVariant works, but looking at the docs I don't see how it would help at all.

Comment: I was thinking that, in combination with QJsonValue it could deal with the whole type checking system for you, and you could get the output as a nice string