# Pass templated function as a std::function and choose template argument later

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to construct a function `tune` that takes a templated function via `std::function` and initializes a series of that function based on a `std::integer_sequence`. I am not sure whether this is possible, and I am stuck. I made a working example that shows what I aim to achieve: a generic function that takes another function and an integer list as an argument. I would like to be able to use the syntax that is in the two lines commented out in the bottom, because with the working code, I have to make a `tune` function for each function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<int I> void print_value() { std::cout << I << std::endl; }
template<int I> void print_value_squared() { std::cout << I*I << std::endl; }

template<int... Is>
void tune_print_value(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    (print_value<Is>(), ...);
}

/* NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS...
template<class Func&&, int... Is>
void tune(std::function<Func> f, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...)
{
    (f<Is>(), ...);
}
*/

int main()
{
    std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3> is;
    tune_print_value(is);

    // I would like:
    // tune(print_value, is);
    // tune(print_value_squared, is);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with a simple function pointer or `std::function` (as it can only point to one instance of a particular template!) but what you can do though is to **wrap each function** `print_value` or `print_value_squared` **in a corresponding struct**

```
struct print_value {  
  template <int I>
  static constexpr int impl() {
    std::cout << I << std::endl;
    return I;
  }
};
```

This struct then holds the templated implementation as a **`static` member function with a predefined name** such as `impl` (sadly you can't use `operator ()` like for a functor as it [is not allowed to be `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776545/9938686))

Your tune function then takes this `struct` as a template argument and "magically" (in C++20 you could create a concept for this [as follows](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dK3fIpVl8fIeJsdp), prior to it you might use SFINAE and `std::enable_if` [as follows](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WzTnpsgopC2fmhvx)) accesses the wrapped template function `impl`.

```
template<class Func, int... Is>
auto tune(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) {
  return (Func::template impl<Is>(), ...);
}
```

You will need the [keyword `template` as a qualifier](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=only-template-keyword-as-qualifier-c) in this case to tell the compiler that the member function is a template.

You can then call the `tune`function like

```
tune<print_value>(is);
```

[Try it here with a static member function `impl`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dAZlfKTSX7trTQpK) or [here with a non-static `operator()`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ypBvMRQIKmR8UFLH).

Comment: Thanks, that is a cool solution. Could you maybe expand your answer with the `concept` and the `enable_if` with some additional explanation? It looks interesting, but the C++ level of the code is high and requires some elaboration for me.

Comment: @Chiel You are welcome! I will explain it here briefly. Without a `concept` or `std::enable_if` the code assumes implicitly that your `struct` matches a certain pattern, in this case that it has a member function which is templated, takes an integer as template argument and returns an integer. Somebody might look at the code and without having a look at the implementation won't be able to say what the requirements for this class `Func` are.

Comment: @Chiel In C++11 up to C++17 you would use `std::enable_if` with SFINAE for this. The compiler will insert the template arguments into the function signature and if it will fail at it it will not cause an error but instead look for matching implementations. In this case [`std::enable_if` does not hold a `typedef type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) if its template argument evaluates to `false`. You can include this `std::enable_if` template anywhere in the function signature, generally either as an additional template argument or like here on the return type.

Comment: @Chiel In this case I have chosen `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(Func::template impl<int{}>()),int>, int>` which means enable this function only if this template has a static function member which is templated for `int` and (`int{}`) returns an `int` (the second `int` above). If the template argument Func does respect that then the return type of the function `tune` will be `int` (the last `int` above) as well. If it does not respect that it will silently ignore this template and look for a function which is a better match (if there is any).

Comment: @Chiel In C++20 (be aware though, no compiler fully supports C++20 yet but they should in the following months) you can formalise this and create a `concept` which is a named set of requirements that a suiting template argument would have to respect. In this case I defined a `concept ImplFunc` which requires the argument to have a static or non-static member function (I think there is no way of enforcing a static member function in a concept) which is templated with an `int` and returns an `int`. Both help a user to understand what the implicit requirements for a template argument are.

Comment: @Chiel Actually I was wrong, you can write a constraint that only works with static functions as well. E.g. something like `std::same_as<decltype(T::template impl<int{}>()), int>;`. [Try it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sjAAuEVhm50Vug1I)