# Can a class member function be invoked without an object?

Tags: c++

I was learning the history about Lambda's in C++ and saw the following code (which is not lambda) but I am surprised how it Works

```
struct Printer{
void operator() (int x) const{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
 }
};

 int main(){
   std::vector <int> vint;
   //doing it the C++ 03 way
    vint.push_back(1);
    vint.push_back(7);

 std::for_each(vint.begin(),vint.end(), Printer());

}
```

How is the `Printer()` call in the `for_each` function working?

Comment: Printer() will create a temporary Printer object and call operator()(int x) on for each value in vint.

Comment: The key here is that `Printer()` is not a call that happens in `for_each`.

Comment: You want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776445/why-cant-operator-of-stateless-functor-be-static/56714863 . I heard that `static operator()` is proposed for a future C++ standard.

Comment: You will understand the code better if you rewrite it like this, at least for yourself: `std::for_each(vint.begin(),vint.end(), Printer{} );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Printer()` is an instance of the `Printer` class. It will result in a temporary object of type `Printer` which is passed to `std::for_each`.

This is the object on which `operator()` is called by `std::for_each` internally.

Without an object of type `Printer`, it is not possible to call the `operator()` member function.

Comment: so it is a compiler thing? OR is it due to the `for_each` function

Comment: @IcanCode I don't understand your question, could you elaborate? `Printer()` used as an expression creates a temporary object, it is _not_ a function call. That is not special to `for_each` and also not compiler-dependent.

Comment: @IcanCode `for_each` isnt magic. Its just a loop. You can see an example implementation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each. Maybe you understand your code better if you do `Printer printer;  std::for_each(vint.begin(),vint.end(), printer);`. It is an insntance that is passed to `for_each` and then the algorithm does call the member method on that instance

Answer (score 4):

> Can a class member function be invoked without an object?

If it is a static member function then yes, it can be invoked without instance of the class.

If it is a non-static member function, then no, it can not be invoked without instance of the class. The example `operator()` function is a non-static member function, so it cannot be called without an instance.

> How is the Printer() call in the for_each function working?

`Printer()` is syntax for value initialisation of a temporary object. The temporary instance of `Printer` class is passed as an argument into `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 2):

Here `Printer()` constructs an object that is used by `for_each`. It is not a function that is called. The function that is called is `Printer()`'s `operator()()`

It works because `for_each` is a template function that applies `()` to its third argument without caring what the third argument really is :

`for_each` is defined something like this,

```
template <typename Iter, typename sth> sth for_each(Iter start, Iter end, sth f){
  
  while(start != end) f(*start ++);
  return f;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `std::for_each` is confusing (you provide a callable which is called by the algorithm), replace it with

```
 for (auto i: vint) Printer()(i);
```

which does the same thing: make a temporary object and call operator() with the needed parameter.

Comment: I think this line actually creates a temporary object for each i?

Comment: @Sebastian It probably does if the compiler doesn't optimize it. I didn't say it was better, but it can be clearer on what's happening.

Comment: Yes, and very nice to read. Just wanted to point out this minor difference.